# Cross-platform way to write Unicode to a file

Tags: c++, boost, unicode, cross-platform, boost-filesystem

I use Boost 1.60.0 on Windows, but I'm writing a cross-platform program. I'm trying to save filenames into a file and read them out later. The file may be text or binary and its encoding does not matter. I get the filenames by iterating through a directory using boost::filesystem::directory_iterator.

The filenames may contain Unicode characters and I can't find a cross-platform way to write or read them.

On Linux I can do it with ofstream and ifstream using boost::filesystem::path class's << and >> operators.

On Windows, however, I need to use wofstream and wifstream and imbue them with a UTF-8 locale, like so:

```
std::wofstream outFile("./outfile");
boost::locale::generator gen;
outFile.imbue(gen("UTF-8"));
```

And then use << and >> operators.

So, I currently have different code for Windows and for Linux, but I'd prefer a solution that doesn't require me to write different code for different systems.

Comment: Which encoding do you want the file to have?

Comment: Please post a short but complete program showing the problem. You have to figure out if the problem is with reading the file names, or with writing Unicode text to a file.

Comment: The problem is with writing the Unicode text to a file. I didn't post any code, because I write the standard c++ way (ofstream operator<<).

I have later learned that the problem only happens on Windows and I have already found a solution for Windows, but I want a prettier cross-platform solution. Perhaps I should rewrite the question and try to make it clearer?